# How can I see Wikidata's largest editors?

Tags: wiki, statistics, wikidata

I wonder how I can see Wikidata's users who made the most edits, along with the number of edits that each of them have made.

This [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_Wikipedians_by_number_of_edits) lists the Wikipedia's users who made the most edits: I am looking for the same for Wikidata.

Comment: You’ve already checked [this page](http://stats.wikimedia.org/wikispecial/EN/TablesWikipediaWIKIDATA.htm#editor_activity_levels), right?

Comment: @Alex: Please post an answer with that link, otherwise I will do it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [this page](https://stats.wikimedia.org/wikispecial/EN/TablesWikipediaWIKIDATA.htm#editor_activity_levels) that gives you some rankings, but as of 31/01/2019 is no longer maintained — it has transitioned to [Wikimedia Statistics](https://stats.wikimedia.org/v2/#/all-projects).

[This page](https://stats.wikimedia.org/v2/#/all-projects/contributing/top-editors/normal|table|last-month|~total|monthly) gives you the top editors list along with the number of edits each of them made.